# USB Ports fail to work

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive

Machine: HP Pavilion 15" (2015) [Laptop]

OS: Manjaro Linux

Issue (very shortly summarized): USB Ports do not work.

How did this happen?: I plugged in a malfunctioning a cheap USB WiFi adapter (originally for my Raspberry Pi 2, it stopped working on it, so decided to plug it into my laptop to see what's up).

Details: Okay so as the I explained earlier, my USB ports do not work - but they did work for that particular USB WiFi adapter (it showed up in `lsusb`!) and also worked to transfer photos from an old Sony HandyCam. Wireless mouse does not work. External hard disks do not work. USB Pendrives do not work. Plugging my Android phone in also didn't work, neither the laptop nor the phone recognized each other, phone didn't even start to charge itself.

Interestingly, internal webcam still works, also the SD card reader also works perfectly fine.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 064e:930a Suyin Corp. HP Truevision HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Also, inbuilt keyboard, touchpad, Ethernet port, HDMI port, DVD drive, SD card reader, webcam, internal microphone, bluetooth, WiFi work perfectly fine.

(Note: When an SD card is plugged in into the SD carder - it does show up in `lsusb`)

Another important fact: BIOS is unable to detect an Ubuntu live USB stick.

This raises a question, is it possible to break every USB port on a system, but pre installed devices that work via USB still work?

Some further clarification:
USB ports do not seem to respond to *any* USB device. Absolutely nothing.

Comment: Did you restart the PC?

Comment: @Moab absolutely. No help.

Comment: There are malicious usb devices out there that discharge high voltage when plugged in and destroy the usb controller on the mobo, not sure if this is your case. I would trash that device regardless.

Comment: @Moab I am certain this was not malicious, the USB WiFi adapter worked as intended - until I decided to put the raspberry pi and it in a box for an year or two. (and yes I have trashed that device to prevent someone else hurting their machine)

Comment: I assume you checked the bios settings for usb.

Comment: When you plug a device, do you see anything at all in the logs? Complete lack of message probably means a hardware issue (broken port, as in, for good).

Comment: I checked the BIOS, nothing relevant there.
And unfortunately, I see no changes in logs (I did `sudo dmesg | less`)...
Every USB port is affected FYI.

Comment: While you're in the BIOS, can you check what the options for USB are? Not boot devices, but generally speaking. I'm afraid I'm partly with Moab on this one: could be that your USB dongle got your USB controller fried, pro'bly not intentionally, though.

Comment: First question to ask: does your external USB port provides any VBUS voltage/power?

Comment: @Ale..chenski I plugged in a USB pendrive with an inbuilt LED. It didn't glow... I don't there is any power in the USB ports - seem to be completely dead.

Comment: I have concluded that my laptop suffers from a hardware failure and this not a software issue.